# Carrierwave - Polymorphic with default_url issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave, polymorphic-associations

I have a Photo Model that Is going to be a polymorphic model.  If I submit my parent model and save it.  If it doesn't have any photos, when I do to display the default_url of a photo it won't show anything because there is no photo.  When a photo is attached to a model, meaning there is only one, it will return a default_url when the field is null but when there is no results, it doesn't return a default_url.  I don't want to enter null records just to fix the default_url issue.

I have found that if i do the following it will return the default_url but not sure this is the best

```
ImageUploader.new.default_url(:small) if @photos.blank?
```

This works but it is sloppy..i think.  Anyone have a better idea?  Maybe a find method on the photos model or something better that will return an object that will have Valid urls whether there is something there or not.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Concerns
  include Guidable

  default_scope :order => 'photos.order DESC'

  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true      
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  def attachable?
    !!self.attachable
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question but still not convinced this is the best option

```
module PhotosHelper

  def photo_url(photo, size)
    defined?(photo.image) ? photo.image.url(size) : ImageUploader.new.send(size).default_url
  end

end
```

Would prefer to have the model just return something if there are no images.